# How to get external IP without relying on third party servers?

Tags: routes, ip, ip-address, nat

Is there any way i can retrieve the external IP address without making a connection outside the network?

Maybe by asking the router somehow?

Does the OS know what IP I have if I am behind a router?

All methods on StackOverflow recommend some kind of third party provider, but I want my application to be independent of other servers.

EDIT: The best solution ive found yet is this: http://code.google.com/p/csharp-upnp-portmapper/

Which rely on UPnP.

Comment: No, there is no generally applicable way to do this. That is why the answers you have found require contacting an outside source.

Comment: What if there are two routers?

Comment: with 2 routers, you got 3 ips: internal, middle, external. to get the ip of the middle or external you need to ask someone at that network.

Comment: Does it exist any kind of standard that could be used? like UPnP or NAT-PmP?

Comment: Yes, the UPnP is the way to go, see also https://superuser.com/questions/420243/how-to-get-the-wan-ip-from-a-router-using-upnp-ssdp to get some idea, altough none of the solutions is very specific. Of course if the router itself is behind a NAT you will not get the outermost IP - but maybe it could be possible to apply UPnP recursively...

Answer (score 1):

If the router have a webinterface, you can fetch the status page in the webinterface of the router, and parse the ip-adress out of the html.

php exemple for a Telenor 4G router

```php
<?php
$url = "http://192.168.0.1/platform.cgi?page=home.htm";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match("/IP Address: [^0-9]+(?<ip>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3})</", $page, $matches);
$ip = $matches['ip'];
echo $ip
?>
```

as most routers require username and passwords, you proberly want to use curl to post thouse and then fetch the page after you logged in.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about something like this but i want it to work on most routers not just my own.

Comment: As there is no standard for routers to report the extarnal ip, if you don't trust an webservice for external ip, my advise is to set up a list of them, if one fails, try the next in the list, or try all and use the ip that you got from most of them, my prefered source for the moment is http://dns.loopia.se/checkip/checkip.php